# Illegal characters in path wen add user to role in ASP MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 ASP.net, I try to add user account to role:
my code is:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
        UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }
        Roles.AddUserToRoles(model.UserName, new[] { "Admin" });
```

and my web.conf is:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider ="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="AUI_Connection2" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

and i get “Illegal characters in path”??

Comment: Is the DB connection string setup correctly?

Comment: <add name="AUI_Connection2" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;&#xD;&#xA;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AIU TS-20140116090888.mdf&quot;;&#xD;&#xA;       Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: If that is indeed your connection string, it doesn't understand &#xD; and &#xA; most likely... what is that for?

Comment: I don't know from where they come!!

Comment: <add name="AUI_Connection2" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AIU TS-20140116090888.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> but still have the same error?!?!

Comment: what about / | &quot; ??

Comment: $quot; is cool; Entity Framework uses it.  It may not actually be the connection string, you have to dig deeper into the error.  Is there a stack trace?